# Reading all JSONs in a folder and getting their strings

Tags: node.js, json, database

There is a folder with a lot of JSON files and all of them got an object called `"name"`
I want to get their strings and turn them into a string like this

```
name0=UsernameExample;name1=Flowers;name2=Test; ...
```

*the number after name is the index/count of the json, like if its name48, its the 48th json*
This far I only tried to read the JSONs from the folder but I failed *of course*

```
let s = "";
  fs.readdir('/tmp/userdb/', (files) => {
  files.each(file => {
    name = file[file.keys()[0]]; 
  })})
```

I can already convert this

```
var other_users = (serialize({
      "sid0": 0,
      "name0": "user1",
      "pays0": "8521",
      "avatar0": "357",
      "onlinescore0": "50"
    }));
```

to this:

```
sid0=0;name0=user1;pays0=8521;avatar0=357;onlinescore0=50
```

with this const

```
const serialize = obj =>
  Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`).join(';')
```

And I want to send the result to the user with this way

```
if (req.query.d === 'getRandomPlayers') {
    
    var sessionid = req.body.player_sid
    let user = require("./tmp/userdb/" + sessionid + ".json")
    
    var current_user = (serialize({
      player_name: user.name
    }));
      
    res.send("method_id=1665;" + current_user);
  }
```

It should be like `res.send("method_id=1665;" + current_user + thefinalresult);`
`thefinalresult` is what this all should go. `current_user` and other stuff is not related to this question.

Comment: Do you think JSON.stringify() works in this case?

Comment: No idea actually, never tried it before...

Comment: please use JSON.stringify() and let me know if it is working or not

Comment: `let data = JSON.stringify({test: hello,test2: 13483242421}); res.send(data)`

Yeah it works, I get `{"test":"hello","test2":13483242423}`

Comment: Wait, what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: Look at the first part of the question, I said that I want to load a folder full of JSONs and read the object "name" in each one of them (all of them got it) and then convert it to a string like this `name0=UsernameExample;name1=Flowers;name2=Test; ...` I also mentioned I can do it with the const serialize. The main problem here is to load all JSON files and then get each one of their `"name"` objects.

Comment: Can you show an example of what a sample `JSON` file would look like?

Comment: `{"53874745":{"avatar":"372","name":"BILLY","onlinescore":"1","pays":"8758"}}` this should turn into `sid0=154261730;name0=SAMMIE;pays0=8521;avatar0=357;onlinescore0=9;` (I can already do this format with const serialize) `sid0` is the filename of the json, the jsons are named after each user's sessionid. `name0` comes from the `name` in the json. `pays0` is `8521` for every user. `avatar0` comes from `avatar` in the json. `onlinescore0` comes from `onlinescore` in the json. the 0 you see after every value (sid0, name0 ..) is the index/count of the json/user,

Comment: like if it was 48th user, it would be `sid48, name48 ...`

Comment: If you need a full example `sid0=154261730;name0=SAMMIE;pays0=8521;avatar0=357;onlinescore0=9;
sid1=154261758;name1=JESSEY;pays1=8521;avatar1=480;onlinescore1=30;sid2=154261742;name2=LYNCIA;pays2=8521;avatar2=500;onlinescore2=134;sid3=154261769;name3=ANI;pays3=8758;avatar3=578;onlinescore3=47;sid4=154260898;name4=KIMMY;pays4=8521;avatar4=596;onlinescore4=103;`

Comment: @beneems have a look at my answer, I think that should cover it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an example `JSON` files inside `/tmp/userdb/` has the following structure,

```
{
  "53874745": {
    "avatar": "372",
    "name": "BILLY",
    "onlinescore": "1",
    "pays": "8758"
  }
}
```

you could do something like the following:

```js
const { promisify } = require("util");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

async function process(excludedSessionId) {
  try {
    const entries = [];

    // get a list of all `JSON` files
    const jsonFiles = await readdir(
      path.join(__dirname, "./tmp/userdb/")
    ).then(
      (files) => files.filter(
        (file) => path.extname(file) === ".json" && !file.includes(excludedSessionId)
      )
    );

    // iterate through a list of all `JSON` files & read their content
    for (const [index, file] of jsonFiles.entries()) {
      const content = await readFile(
        path.join(__dirname, "./tmp/userdb/", file)
      ).then(JSON.parse);

      // create an object for a new entry
      const key = `sid${index}`;
      const keyValue = Object.keys(content)[0];

      // use the `spread syntax` to include the rest of the
      // properties in a new entry 
      const entry = {
        [key]: keyValue,
        ...content[keyValue],
      };

      entries.push(entry);
    }

    console.log(entries[0]);
    // { 
    //    sid0: '53874745', 
    //    avatar: '372', 
    //    name: 'BILLY', 
    //    onlinescore: '1', 
    //    pays: '8758'
    //  }

    const result = entries.map((entry) => serialize(entry)).join(";");

    console.log(result);
    // sid0=53874745;avatar=372;name=BILLY;onlinescore=1;pays=8758;
    // sid1=154261758;avatar=480;name=JESSEY;onlinescore=30;pays=8521;

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
process("154261742");
```

Then, if you'd want to use this function in a callback of your route controller, you could do something like the following:

```js
app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
  // ...
  const excludedSessionId = req.body.player_sid;

  process(excludedSessionId)
    .then(result => {
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send("Something went wrong.");
    });
});
```

References:

- [Spread syntax (...) - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [async function - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder how can I use the final result in res.send? I've tried res.send(result) and res.send(process) but it didn't work.

Comment: @beneems edit your answer and show what your controller/route handler looks like and what you're trying to dod exactly

Comment: By the way, I edited my JSON and it looks like this now: `{"sessionid":"53874745","avatar":"372","name":"BILLY","onlinescore":"1","pays":"8758"}`

Comment: @beneems I am not sure what exactly you're doing there or how this new `process` is being used in that context, but I edited my question with an example of how you'd use this new `process` function in your route handler if you wanted to use it there.

Comment: @beneems you're still able to get what you need with the example above right? even with the new `JSON`?

Comment: Yeah, it works amazing, thank you! The user gives it's own session id with POST body as `player_sid=27939831` (example sessionid) and I wonder how can I make process() exclude `./tmp/userdb/27939831.json` (because the current user is already given with current_user  in the res.send so there is no need for the current user seeing theirselves in the respond twice)

Comment: @beneems just pass an argument to `process` that takes a session id that needs to be excluded and expand on the `filter` method that I used to exclude any files that are not `JSON` files

Comment: I could use `content.sessionid` but content is under the filter so... that's not possible or I can't do it...

Comment: @beneems didn't you say get that information in the body of the request? Get it from the body then pass it to the function.

Comment: Could you edit your question or show it here please?

Comment: Thank you but after I've done what you did, all of the process I used started to give this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)` in the `const content = await readFile` line

All of the JSON files I got are okay, don't know why it gives this error.

Comment: @beneems The change I did excludes the file that you don't want to process. The error that you're seeing has something to do with reading files that are not JSON but you're trying to process them as such. Are you sure you didn't make any other changes and/or changes to the file themselves? I have this running on my local machine and it works as expected.

Comment: I didn't do any other changes in the JSON. But I made a root get a body object and then write it in the JSON but I don't think that's the problem cause the JSON doesnt have any errors.

Comment: @beneems that could definitely be a problem, that's what the error message is saying. Perhaps whatever you're doing and saving into a `JSON` file is not valid `JSON`